# SQL update null values with another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, self-join

I have written this query to update null values from another column which i have extracted using JOIN however, it shows syntex error and not working.

I would like to populate `PropertyAddress values` from  `ifnull(a.propertyaddress,b.propertyaddress)` for that i have written this query.

[image]

```
select a.ParcelID,a.PropertyAddress, b.ParcelID,b.PropertyAddress,
ifnull(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
from housingdata a
join housingdata b
    on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    and a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
where a.PropertyAddress is null;


update a 
set PropertyAddress = ifnull(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
from housingdata a  << getting syntex error here*
join housingdata b
on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
and a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
where a.PropertyAddress is null;
```

however it shows an error in from clause in update statement.

Comment: In a `select` statement, you need to specify what and then which table `from`, but in an `update` statement you specify which table is updated first and then what to `set` in it. The `join` doesn't really differ, though as pointed out, you might want the join to sit with the main table. `where` clauses are also identical between them.

Answer (score 3):

`UPDATE ... JOIN` syntax in MySQL is different from SQL-Server, you might want to do that, and `set PropertyAddress` might use right alias because there are two tables holding `PropertyAddress` from your query.

your logic might set `a.PropertyAddress = b.PropertyAddress` directly because there is a condition `a.PropertyAddress is null`.

```
update housingdata a  
join housingdata b
on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
and a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID 
set a.PropertyAddress = b.PropertyAddress
where a.PropertyAddress is null;
```

Comment: got error `column 'PropertyAddress' in field list is an ambigious' ` @D-Shih

Comment: I edit my answer and add some suggestions.

Comment: perfect, worked:) Many thanks.

Comment: @alex No problem glad to help